# How do I prevent xcodebuild in Xcode 9 from creating extraneous metadata files?

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode9

After the upgrade to Xcode 9 on our TeamCity-based CI Server, xcodebuild no longer exports ONLY the .ipa artifact. It now also creates three meta-data files that I'd prefer it not create.

```
com.mycompany.ourapp.ipa
DistributionSummary.plist
ExportOptions.plist
Packaging.log
```

Is there a way to tell xcodebuild I only want the .ipa? I could of course delete the three meta-data files in a post-build shell script, but it'd be cleaner if xcodebuild never created them in the first place.